Density of smooth functions in $L^2$
It is well known that $C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ is a dense subset of $L^2(\Omega)$. Here we consider that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain from $\mathbb{R}^N$. My question is:
If for some $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ with the property that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$ a.e. on $\Omega$ we have that $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}\subset C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, i.e.:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \Vert f_n-f\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}=0$$
can we assume without losing the generality that $0\leq f_n(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in\Omega$?
More precisely if we take $T:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1],\ T(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x<0\\ x, x\in [0,1]\\ 1, x>1\end{cases}$, is it true that:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \Vert T(f_n)-T(f)\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \Vert T(f_n)-f\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}=0$$
??
It is clear that $T(f_n)\in L^2(\Omega)$ for any $n\geq 1$.

The second claim is true, as $|T(x) - T(y)| \leq |x - y|$ for all $x, y$. But it doesn’t directly prove your first claim, since $T(f_n)$ may no longer be smooth. To prove the first claim, combine the following facts:

Since $0 \leq f \leq 1$ a.e., $\sqrt{f}$ is well-defined and $0 \leq \sqrt{f} \leq 1$ a.e.;
Thus, there is a sequence $g_n \in C_c(\Omega)$ s.t. $\|g_n - \sqrt{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$. Then by the second claim, $\|T(g_n) - \sqrt{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$;
By Stone-Weierstrass and using a smooth bump function, as $T(g_n) \in C_c(\Omega)$ and $\|T(g_n)\|_\infty \leq 1$, we may, for each $n$, choose a $h_n \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\|h_n\|_\infty \leq 1$ s.t. $\|T(g_n) - h_n\|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{n}$. As $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, this implies $\|T(g_n) - h_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$, so $\|h_n - \sqrt{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$;
As $\|h_n\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq 1$ and $\|\sqrt{f}\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq 1$, we have,

$$\begin{split}
|h_n^2(x) - f(x)| &\leq |h_n(x)||h_n(x) - \sqrt{f(x)}| + |\sqrt{f(x)}||h_n(x) - \sqrt{f(x)}|\\
&\leq 2|h_n(x) - \sqrt{f(x)}|
\end{split}$$
a.e. Hence, $\|h_n^2 - f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq 2\|h_n - \sqrt{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$. And $h_n^2 \in C_c(\Omega)$ with $0 \leq h_n^2 \leq 1$, so we can set $f_n = h_n^2$.
